# DXA deleted Localization Interceptor

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

The new version of [DXA Java](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/) in `master` branch has no `LocalizationInterceptor`, and I was wondering why? We have some problems with the context where localizations are being mixed when getting content, and it's getting content from a different Publication, so we were thinking that maybe is there an issue in the 1.6 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `master` branch represents the latest stable version. As mentioned in the `README.md` of the repository, this may be a pre-release version (tagged as DXA x.y Sprint z). Updated each development Sprint (approx. bi-weekly).

That is exactly the case at the moment, since the master branch was last updated with the DXA 2.0 CTP 1 release. DXA 2.0 is the merge between DD4T and DXA, and contains a different data model and architecture, the latest release is a Community Technology Preview, a bit like a beta, be it more stable yet not feature complete to be a final release.

If you are looking for the latest DXA 1.x release, that is DXA 1.7, see also the releases tab (https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/releases), or use the release branch https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/1.7

I'm not aware of any issues around localizations in DXA 1.6, both DXA 1.6 and 1.7 passed the same acceptance test before release, but there could always be something we have missed of course. However, if trying to see if something changed I would suggest you compare to the `release/1.7` branch, since the changes in DXA 2.0 CTP 1 are for a different architecture.